# Fatal error for PHPExcel classes while configuring it with WAMP (PHP 5.3.5)

Tags: php, phpexcel

While working with PHPExcel in my application I got following errors

In PHPExcel/Autoloader.php file for line “PHPExcel_Shared_ZipStreamWrapper::register();”,

```
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/wamp/www/xxxx/site//common/class/PHPExcel_Shared_ZipStreamWrapper.class.php' (include_path='C:\wamp\www\xxxx\site\common\html_purifier;.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\xxxx\site\config\bootstrap.php on line 27
```

and for line “PHPExcel_Shared_String::buildCharacterSets();”

```
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/wamp/www/xxxx/site//common/class/PHPExcel_Shared_String.class.php' (include_path='C:\wamp\www\xxxx\site\common\html_purifier;.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\xxxx\site\config\bootstrap.php on line 27
```

I'm using wamp with php 5.3.5. and zip xml and gd2 extensions are enable on my local machine.
Please help me for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to C:\wamp\www\xxxx\site\config\bootstrap.php suggests you're working with some kind of framework: does it have an autoloader that could be conflicting with or overriding PHPExcel's autoloader?

The reference to

> '/wamp/www/xxxx/site//common/class/PHPExcel_Shared_ZipStreamWrapper.class.php'

seems to confirm this.
as something is changing the filename to include ".class" as part of the filename, and it's ignoring PHPExcel's own autoloader that splits a class name to match its directory structure

If you're using a standard framework such as ZF or Symfony, then you should register PHPExcel with that framework. If it's a homebrew, make sure your autoloader is SPL registered

Comment: Hello Mark, I registered PHPExcel in my project's autoloader function and it is working for me. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be having double slashes in your path:

/wamp/www/xxxx/site**//**common

So it's probably a path issue and the autoloader isn't able to load the file because the path is wrong.